# Image loses aspect ratio when resizing

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I am losing my mind trying to figure out why does my image keeps losing the aspect ratio when I resize my window to a certain point.

The HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sandro Sousa's portfolio.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <script defer src="app.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

 <header>

     <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="brand-title">Sandro Sousa Rivera</div>

            <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>

            </a>

            <div class="navbar-links">
                <ul>
                         <li><a href="#personal">About Me</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#technologies">Technologies</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#cv">CV</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
     </nav>

</header>

<div class="sections">

<section id="personal" class="hidden">

    <p>Hola chicos, soy PERSONAL</p>

<div class="section-content" id="about-me">
    
    <img class="profile-image" src="resources/profile1.jpeg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>

</section>

<section id="technologies" class="hidden">

    <p>Hola chicos soy <b>TECHNOLOGIES</b></p>

    <div class="section-content" id="technologies">



</div>

</section>

<section id="projects" class="hidden">

    <p>Hola chicos soy <b>PROJECTS</b></p>

    <div class="section-content" id="projects">



    </div>
    
</section>

<section id="cv" class="hidden">

    <p>Hola chicos soy CV</p>

    <div class="section-content" id="cv">



    </div>
    
</section>

<section id="contact" class="hidden">

    <p>Hola chicos soy Contact</p>

    <div class="section-content" id="technologies">



    </div>
    
</section>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
 /* ▼ WEB BODY ▼ */

 
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@300;600&display=swap');

 *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }


  body{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(250, 248, 235);
    font-family: 'Titillium Web','arial';
  }


  .sections{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 10%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }

  section{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }

  .section-content{
    gap: 5%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 5%;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }


  .hidden{
    padding-top: 10%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s;

  }

  .show{
    opacity: 1;

  }


/* ▼ NAVIGATION MENU ▼ */

.brand-title{
    color: rgb(250, 248, 235);
}

.navbar{
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    color: rgb(250, 248, 235);
}

.brand-title{
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar-links li{
    padding: 1rem;
    list-style: none;

}

.navbar-links li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(250, 248, 235);
    align-items: center;

    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar a:hover{
    color: rgb(212, 212, 212);

    opacity: 0.7;
}

.toggle-button{
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar{
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(250, 248, 235);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {

    .hidden{
        padding-top: 30%;
    }

    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li a {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
}

/* ▼ ABOUT ME SECTION ▼ */

.profile-image{
    width: 25%;
}

/* OLD CODE FOR THE NAVBAR

 nav {

    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 50%;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

nav ul {
    line-height: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}


nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;

    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: rgb(212, 212, 212);

    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

HERE IS A [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/sandropolixe/pen/qBJLNME) OF THE WHOLE PROJECT INCLUDING CSS:

I have read every post and implemented a lot of solutions, even tried ChatGPT but nothing seems to work.

When I take the image out the "section" tag it seems to work just fine.

I really hope you can help me with this :)

Comment: Please check your code. We cannot see an image. Better if you put code as a runnable snippet into your question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. why does my image keeps losing the aspect ratio

because you're setting the `width` only on the image without the `height`:

```
.profile-image{
    width: 25%;
    aspect-rati0:1/1; /* this will make the image a square */
}
```

> 2. losing the aspect ratio when I resize my window to a certain point
>    because you defined the rule for the width inside this `media query`:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {

.profile-image{
    width: 25%;
}
}
```

3. solution: adding a height or an aspect ratio, and decide if you want that rule inside or outside of the `@media`